# how to use python to select first X columns and last Y columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to select column 1 to 8 and the last column from a data frame. I have some dumb way to do that

step 1: select first 8 column

```
df1 = df[df.columns[range(9)]]
```

step 2: select last column

```
df2 = df[df.columns[-1]]
```

step 3: combine step1 and step2

```
df1.join(df2)
```

is there a better way to do that in one step instead of 3 steps?

Comment: Please add the library you're using as a tag to your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use smart column indexing:

```
df.iloc[:, list(range(9)) + [-1]]
```

Comment: I tired to use [range(9)] instead of list(range(9). It does not work. Can you explain why we can only use list here instead of []?

Comment: `[range(9)]` is a list of one item (a generator). `list(range(9))` is a list of nine integer numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Concat** from Pandas. This works as same as **CBIND**.

```
new_df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0:8],df.iloc[:,-1:]],axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @DYZ answer. You can use another combination to select first and few last columns

```
df.iloc[ :[1] + list(range(-10, 0)]
```

Answer (score -3):

Try using head/tail in the dataframe.

```
print(df.head(8))

print(df.tail(8))
```

Comment: Head and tail operate on rows, not on columns.